# Reliable methods which require specific thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Given a method which must be executed on main thread:

```
    -(void)methodRequiringMainThread{

     int a=1;

    }
```

And a caller to it:

```
    -(void)callerToMethod{

      if(![NSThread isMainThread]){
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self methodRequiringMainThread]}); 
      } else {
       [self methodRequiringMainThread];
      }

}
```

What is the best practice for insuring that the the method is called on main thread?

1. Annotate in interface comment and hope all callers check for main
   thread and dispatch as necessary (as above).
2. Wrap the private method in a
   public method which simply checks for main thread and dispatches the
   private method as necessary.
3. Insert an NSAssert in the called method

I've seen issues relying on #1 + #3, and I don't like it because you can't test for a caller which winds up on another thread rarely.

I also don't like it because there is no specific functionality for revealing this requirement to the caller in the method signature - its (an important) semi-secret.

I'd prefer to use #2 (or just wrap the contents in a block internally and check), because it guarantees the main thread regardless of the caller.

UIKit doesn't seem to do any explicit checking or exposure either, which is strange at this point. Seems like there should be some sort of functionality built-in, even if its only internal to XCode, which communicates and/or guarantees the thread.

Comment: If have a method that should always run on the main thread, why just not put all its inplementation in dispatch_get_mainqueue block?

Comment: Another option is to make the functional code a block within the method itself and then use logic as in strategy #2 to either execute the block or dispatch it to the right thread.  Minor advantage: one method instead of two to accomplish the purpose.

Comment: I think this is @AlexKosyakov's point, but to restate: option 2 is great, but doesn't require an additional method.  Make the very first line of `methodRequiringMainThread` do the dispatch.

Comment: Yes! This was actually my first response, but it was a bit ugly wrapping the entire contents of the method in the block. Also, since its a sync, I must do the check first, so I actually had to assign a block variable first, then conditionally dispatch at the end, which was a bit weird. I also was not entirely sure of the impact on parameters and return values, especially whether, for example, a passed self needed to be weaked (not illustrated in example)

Comment: So another question I have regarding this approach is ... why doesn't UIKit do this, if UIKit methods must be run on main thread? Why does UIKit allow the caller to make the error?

Comment: I'll speculate: since the most common usages of UIKit methods are going to come from the main thread anyway, it's probably deemed a fair trade to process them more efficiently and make the caller responsible for exceptional cases.  (I actually think it's a long-term benefit to the programmer, being prodded to think about thread implications when using them...but I'm sure that's a by-product rather than a reason.)